# How to place svg icon in toolbar

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I need to replace all of my png icons with with svg - it is my employee request. I am using FFImageLoading. Some of the icons displayed in Pages are displaying properly but the problem is that I can't display svg icon in toolbar (toolbar item and hamburger icon).

I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0.908675 and Xamarin.FFImageLoading - all in version 2.4.11.982.

My `logo.svg` is placed in `MyProject.EmbeddedFiles.Images`.

Here are the code samples I tried:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
{
    IconImageSource = "logo.svg",
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
});

ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
{
    IconImageSource = "MyProject.EmbeddedFiles.Images.logo.svg",
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
});

ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
{
    IconImageSource = ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.EmbeddedFiles.Images.test.svg", typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly),
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
});

ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
{
    IconImageSource = new SvgImageSource(ImageSource.FromResource("MyProject.EmbeddedFiles.Images.test.svg", typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly), 10,10,true),
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
});
```

Neither solution works. My solution based on https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/1105
What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Comment: Make sure that your svg images are added in the proj with build action as `Embedded Resource`

Comment: It is added as embedded resource. I mention that svg files in Pages render correctly.

Comment: You could not directly set the source of icon as svg format . Check https://dev.to/muak_x/creating-custom-imagesource-in-xamarinforms-and-displaying-an-svg-image-to-default-image-controll-4dn7

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @DemoDemo unfortunately not. I removed toolbar and write my own.